# how to check if a JSONArray is empty in java?

Tags: arrays, json, json-rpc

I am working on an android app that get json content of a webservice called "WebUntis". The Json content i am getting looks like:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"req-002",
 "result":[
    {"id":125043,"date":20110117,"startTime":800,"endTime":850,
     "kl":[{"id":71}],
     "te":[{"id":23}],
     "su":[{"id":13}],
     "ro":[{"id":1}]},
    {"id":125127,"date":20110117,"startTime":1055,"endTime":1145,
     "kl":[{"id":71}],
     "te":[{"id":41}],
     "su":[{"id":19}],
     "ro":[{"id":31}]},
...]}
```

As you can see in the result-array there are also other arrays like "kl", "su" and "ro"

I am getting the content of these array and then i store them in an arraylist.
But when one of these array is empty, like;

```
    {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"req-002",
     "result":[
         {"id":125043,"date":20110117,"startTime":800,"endTime":850,
          "**kl":[]**,
          "te":[{"id":23}],
          "su":[{"id":13}],
          "ro":[{"id":1}]},
         {"id":125127,"date":20110117,"startTime":1055,"endTime":1145,
          "kl":[{"id":71}],
          "te":[{"id":41}],
          "su":[{"id":19}],
          "ro":[{"id":31}]},
...]}
```

I am always getting the error **`IndexOutOfRangeException`**,
but I am always telling it that it should not take the empty arrays, this is what I have tried:

```
 JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject(s);
 // Get the result object
 JSONArray arr = jsonResult.getJSONArray("result");

 for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = arr.getJSONObject(i);
    anfangStunde[i] = c.getString("startTime");
    endeStunde[i] = c.getString("endTime");

    // get the jsonarrays (kl, su, ro)
    kl = c.getJSONArray("kl");
    su = c.getJSONArray("su");
    ro = c.getJSONArray("ro");

    // check if kl is not null
    if(kl != null){
       klassenID[i] = kl.getJSONObject(0).getString("id");
    }
    if (klassenID[i] != null) {
       klasse = webuntis.klassenMap.get(klassenID[i]);
       Log.d("ID und Klasse=", "" + klassenID[i] + ";" + klasse);
    }
    // get th ids
    fachID[i] = su.getJSONObject(0).getString("id");
    if (fachID[i] != null) {
       fach = webuntis.faecherMap.get(fachID[i]);
       Log.d("ID und Fach=", "" + fachID[i] + ";" + fach);
    }

    // "Start;Ende;Klasse;Fach;Raum" store in arraylist
    webuntis.stundenPlan.add(anfangStunde[i] + ";" + endeStunde[i] + ";" + klasse + ";" + fach);
    // Write Data into a file for offline use:
 }
```

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If the array is defined in the file **but** is empty, like:

```
...
"kl":[]
...
```

Then `getJSONArray("kl")` will return an *empty* array, but the object is not `null`. Then, if you do this:

```
kl = c.getJSONArray("kl");
if(kl != null){
   klassenID[i] = kl.getJSONObject(0).getString("id");
}
```

`kl` is *not* `null` and `kl.getJSONObject(0)` will throw an exception - there is no first element in the array.

Instead you can check the `length()`, e.g.:

```
kl = c.getJSONArray("kl");
if(kl != null && kl.length() > 0 ){
   klassenID[i] = kl.getJSONObject(0).getString("id");
}
```

Comment: nice work `if(kl != null && kl.length() > 0 ){` simple

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `isEmpty()` method, this is the method we use to check whether the list is empty or not. This method returns a Boolean value. It returns true if the list is empty otherwise it gives false. For example:

```
if (!k1.isEmpty()) {
    klassenID[i] = kl.getJSONObject(0).getString("id");     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regular **length()** method. It returns the size of JSONArray. If the array is empty, it will return **0**. So, You can check whether it has elements or not. This also keeps you in track of total elements in the Array, You wont go out of Index.

```
if(k1 != null && k1.length != 0){
     //Do something.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do it...

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call,
                           Response<JsonObject> response) {

        JSONObject jsonObject;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(response.body()));


            JSONArray returnArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("my_array");

            // Do Work Only If Not Null
            if (!returnArray.isNull(0)) {

                for (int l = 0; l < returnArray.length(); l++) {
                    if (returnArray.length() > 0) {

                        // Get The Json Object
                        JSONObject returnJSONObject = returnArray.getJSONObject(l);

                        // Get Details
                        String imageUrl = returnJSONObject.optString("image");

                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call,
                          Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JSONObject and JSONArray from org.json and you have an object like this

```
{
   "createdBy": "4fgdfgdfgd",
   "customers" : null //here customer is supposed to be an array, []
}
```

Then you can do a check like this

```
if(jsonObject.get("customers")==JSONObject.NULL) {
   //do something if it is null
}
```

JSONObject.NULL is a built in constant present in org.json package